# View open transactions in Oracle

Tags: oracle, transactions

How can I see open transactions in Oracle ? I'm doing a custom performance tool, and I'd like to see the number of currently open transactions. Is there a SQL request to do that, or another way to gather this information ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use view [v$transaction](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2170.htm)